# How to set separate column values of SQLite database to seperate Text Views?- Android

Tags: android, sqlite

In my application there is a SQLite database. I need to retrieve data from separate columns (Two columns - name and organization) from the table and I need to set those values to separate text views. This is what I tried.

This is the class where I'm adding my table data to a list.

DBAccess class

```
public class DBAccess {
private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private static DBAccess instance;
String passedVar = null;
private ListView listView;

public DBAccess(Context context) {

    this.openHelper = new AppDB(context);
}

public static DBAccess getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DBAccess(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

public void open() {
    this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        this.database.close();
    }
}


public List<Contacts>getContacts(){
List<Contacts>list = new ArrayList<>();
    if (id != null) {
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE mId = \"" + id + "\"", null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

        Contacts con = new Contacts(cursor.getString(2),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
        list.add(con);

        Contacts con1 = new Contacts(cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("organization")));
        list.add(con1);

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    cursor.close();
}
return list;
}}
```

How do I retrieve those items to this class and set them on these text views (tv1,tv2)?

MainActivity class

```
public class MantraActivity extends MainActivity {
private ViewPager viewPager;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mantra_view);


    DBAccess dba=  new DBAccess(MantraActivity.this);
    dba.open();


    TextView tv1= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView tv2= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

}}
```

Contacts class

```
public class Contacts {

public String mid;
public String name;
public String organization;


public Contacts(String mid, String name, String organization) {
    this.mid = mid;
    this.name = name;
    this.organization = organization;
}

public String getMid() {
    return mid;
}

public void setMid(String mid) {
    this.mid = mid;
}

public String getMantra() {
    return mantra;
}

public void setMantra(String mantra) {
    this.mantra = mantra;
}


   public String getOrganization() {
        return organization;
    }

public void setOrganization(String organization) {
    this.organization = organization;
}
```

}

Comment: What are `mant` and `mant1` ?

Comment: @tahsinRupam-sorry I corrected it. I have added columns separately. Is that wrong?

Comment: Yeah, no need to add two different contacts. Can you please add the Contacts model class too to your question ? It would be rather helpful

Comment: @tahsinRupam-done.please correct me

Comment: Check @cricket_007 's answer please. That got all the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're adding two Contacts from the database for each row... Not sure if that is intended, but here is that fix.

```
for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String mId = cursor.getString(2);
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
    String organization = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("organization"));

    Contacts con = new Contacts(mId, name, organization);
    list.add(con);
}
```

> I need to set those values to separate text views.

Why separate TextViews?
You have an ArrayList, so use a ListView + ArrayAdapter to load each Contact into one row of a list.

```
List<Contacts> contacts = db.getContacts();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.id.simple_list_item_1);
for (Contact c : contacts) {
    adapter.add(c.getName() + " - " + c.getOrganization());
}
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I don't need to show those values in a listview. I need to show them on textviews.

Comment: I'm showing them on TextViews within a Listview. It doesn't make sense to show a list in two single TextViews.

Comment: If you are only returning one Contact with `mId`, then why would you return an ArrayList?

Comment: After adding this code , do I need to set it for textviews? I didn't get u clearly. 

My 'name' field includes 10 records. and Organization has long text.

Comment: No, I have no textview in my answer. length of texts don't matter. The size of the list is dynamic.

Comment: But I need to show it in two separate text views. Your first answer which u added first works well only for one textview.

Comment: @venura so you want your data do be presented in the list view, each database item shown in two separate text views?

Comment: @venura This **does** show in two TextViews. Please **try**

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry but `android.R.id.simple_list_item_1` has only one text view

Comment: @pskink - Yes I need to show the values of separate columns (name and organization columns) in separate text views. I don't need listview.  Was I wrong using public List<Contacts>getContacts(){?

Comment: @pskink I am aware, that's why I concated the strings

Comment: @venura It's only wrong if you expect to return a single item instead of a list

Comment: @venura yes you need a `ListView`, otherwise why would you need a `List<Contacts>` for?

Comment: Thank you @pskink . That means I need to add those values to listview and retrieve it to separate text views?

Comment: @venura Can you explain what issue you have with this code I provided? It should work

Comment: @ cricket_007 - according to my design , I need to use text views. One text view for Name and other one for organization

Comment: @venura see this: https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/ and when using sqlite based data model always use some sort of `CursorAdapter`, not any `BaseAdapter` / `ArrayAdapter` - they are used for different purposes